# image.load_img error in python, Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, anaconda, python-imaging-library

I have the following code

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
    test_image = image.load_img('roi.jpg', target_size = (64, 64),grayscale=True)
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
```

The **roi.jpg** is an image which saved in the same directory. After execution I got the following error

```
test_image = image.load_img('roi.jpg', target_size = (64, 64),grayscale=True)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 345, in load_img raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. ')
ImportError: Could not import PIL.Image. The use of `array_to_img` requires PIL.
```

Please help me to solve this error. I have used `windows 10`
and `python version : Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)`

Comment: So basically that message tells you to install PIL. Have you tried that?

Comment: yeah i have installed the pillow. but didn't solved it.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thanku

Answer (score 3):

You need the PIL module, try the first one else try the second one

```
conda install PIL
conda install Pillow
```

or if both PIL and Pillow exists, uninstall both and re-install PIL

Comment: i have already installed the second one. but that's not the solution

Comment: how about PIL? have you installed it?

Comment: conda install pil
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pil
  - zict
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package. @johnll

Comment: can you uninstall PIL and Pillow and install PIL again?

Comment: @BibinJaimon you can accept my answer if it helped you, thanks.